# I need to check if a string contains a certain pattern using a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that is something like `"Hello 9 you8 [C#587]"` or `"Hello 9 you8 [#587]"`

I need to check if the string contains `"[#numbers]"` or `"[letter#numbers]"` using a regular expression in C#.

Please assist.

kind regards

In actual fact the "letter" part might be a word.

Please help as per update.

Thanks

Comment: Please read 30 minute regex tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: I have tried 
@"[#[0-9]]" and
\\[*.#.[^0-9]\\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

`\[([A-Za-z]+)?#(\d)+\]`

[image]

Comment: It allows `0#0` which is not allowed. Also it has to be one letter before `#`.

Comment: Yes, but it's not a letter: `[letter#numbers]`

Comment: @JohnWoo, thanks I have used @"([a-zA-Z]+#)?\d+") and it gave me the desired result.

Much appreciated!

Comment: @JohnWoo I just tried the above RegEx with the text "Testing 3" and it found a match, which it should not have. Please assist!

Comment: I am using @"([a-zA-Z]+#)?\d+"

Comment: the `#` is inside the group which appears optional. can you move it after `?` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
\[[a-zA-Z]?#\d+\]
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you want something slightly different to @hsz's answer. His will only check the `[letter#numbers]` and not the `[#numbers]`.

Try this:

```
\[[a-zA-Z]?#\d+\]
```

Comment: I check also `[#numbers]` - letter is optional. You have exact the same answer as I have. ;-)

Comment: 5 minutes before you posted your answer.